# Autofac dynamic assembly binding not working in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, autofac, azure-functions-runtime

Not sure how assembly references get resolved in Azure Function but the following code works fine in a console app(I have tried with both .net core console and .net 4.6.1 console). If I try to use the same code in a function app, I would get the error messages I have mentioned in my code comments. I am using latest version (15.10.2046.0) of Functions and Web Job Tools.

Note: I have manually copied myplugin.dll into my function app's bin folder. Same thing I have done with my console app where the same code works.

```
var assemblyRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var pluginPath = Directory.GetFiles(assemblyRoot, $"myplugin.dll").FirstOrDefault();

var pluginAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(pluginPath);

var builder = new ContainerBuilder(); // I am using Autofac
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(pluginAssembly).AsImplementedInterfaces().SingleInstance();

var container = builder.Build();
 // Here I am getting errors like "Unable to find assembly '<assembly>'. Are you missing a private assembly file?" for various referenced assemblies like automapper, MongoDB.Bson etc.

var plugIn = container.Resolve<IPlugin>(); 
// Here I am getting "'IPlugIn' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.'"
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

V1 (NET 4.6):

https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/azure-functions-dependency-injection/

https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/azure-functions-proper-dependency-injection/

http://codingsoul.de/2018/01/19/azure-function-dependency-injection-with-autofac/

V2 (NET Core):

https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/dependency-injection-for-azure-functions/

http://codingsoul.de/2018/06/12/azure-functions-dependency-injection-autofac-on-functions-nuget-package/

Comment: Thank you for effort to direct me to some useful resources. Unfortunately Its same thing what I have already done but directly inside function method instead of creating a bootstrapper. builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes() still doesn't work.